# Can't log in with has_secure_password method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm creating simple own authentication system and helps myself with Railscasts. But I can't deal with a problem.

I have Sessions controller

```
  def create 
    user = User.find_by_username(params[:email])
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to root_path, notice: "Logged in."
    else
      flash.now.alert = "Email or password is invalid."
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

And all the time browser go back to 'sessions#new' page.
Log when I sign up:

```
Started POST "/users" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-05 21:03:38 +0200
Processing by UsersController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NL7mPvVyPMUyQO/WizmXS3O7q4yrUGtyri5rckOlKAo=", "user"=>{"username"=>"john2", "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "password_confirmation"=>"[FILTERED]"}, "commit"=>"Create User"}
   (0.1ms)  begin transaction
  User Exists (0.1ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."username" = 'john2' LIMIT 1
Binary data inserted for `string` type on column `password_digest`
  SQL (0.2ms)  INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "password_digest", "updated_at", "username") VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)  [["created_at", "2014-10-05 19:03:38.346127"], ["password_digest", "$2a$10$4negYTKUz7vWJV0Af3Ja8u86za/l7k/LANKCVmHKz8zxn4JRjgTgu"], ["updated_at", "2014-10-05 19:03:38.346127"], ["username", "john2"]]
   (186.9ms)  commit transaction
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/
Completed 302 Found in 281ms (ActiveRecord: 187.3ms)
```

And log when I try to log in:

```
Started POST "/sessions" for 127.0.0.1 at 2014-10-05 21:08:03 +0200
Processing by SessionsController#create as HTML
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"NL7mPvVyPMUyQO/WizmXS3O7q4yrUGtyri5rckOlKAo=", "username"=>["john2"], "password"=>"[FILTERED]", "commit"=>"Log in"}
  User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users"  WHERE "users"."username" IS NULL LIMIT 1
  Rendered sessions/new.html.erb within layouts/application (1.1ms)
Completed 200 OK in 61ms (Views: 59.2ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
```

I use `has_secure_password` method.

Comment: Doesn't has_secure_password require a password confirmation to match the given password to be valid?

http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html#method-i-has_secure_password

Comment: I mean log in not sign up. Sign up works OK. Authenticate method requires only one argument http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveModel/SecurePassword/ClassMethods.html